# How to check for two keys being held in python, lib: pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to check for 2 keys being held to get a return value, with python using the pynput library, thanks

I've tried many google searches, but no information about my problem seem to appear.

```py
def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.alt and key == Key.print_screen:
       return False
```

I expect this code to return false if I press / hod alt and print screen at the same time, but nothing seems to happen when I do that. And yes, I have coded a listener to this project. This code works, if that

```py
and key == Key.print_screen
```

was removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to do something along the lines of this:

```
combination = [Key.alt, Key.print_screen]
currently_pressed = set()

def _on_press(self, key):
    if key in combination:
        currently_pressed.add(key)

    if currently_pressed == self.combination:
        is_pressed = True
        print('pressed!')
```

More here: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

Forget pyinput for a minute and focus on

```
key == Key.alt and key == Key.print_screen
```

The only way to make this expression return True is both expression on left and right should be True. But I guess `Key.alt` and `Key.print_screen` can't evaluate True at the same time. So, if any of them pressed,

`True and False` or `False and True` will evaluate to `False` so your function will return `None`. Not even a `False`.